# How to properly configure LWR networkbrand loginLogo from cms

Tags: digital-experience, lwr

Since we cannot configure the change password branding in the communities using the LWR template, I've found a work around to retrieve and deploy the metadata on this link:

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Nv6k1UAB/branding-for-lwr-changepassword-page

That works, but I'm not being able to correctly do the reference for the CMS image in the loginLogo tag.

Tried a lot of possibilities...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with the community (even the salesforce guys could not help)

You can let the loginLogoName and the loginLogo tags as is described on that [idea I've commented before](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Nv6k1UAB/branding-for-lwr-changepassword-page).
But what is missing there is this information:

The "**XXXX.networkBranding**" file that seems not be usefull, is supposed to be the logo file you need...

Exactly, you just need put your logo file there on the vscode folder retrieved, and rename it, to be the "XXXX.networkBranding".

Of course the "XXXX" is your network name...